# Maximum execution time For DomPDF in laravel Project

Tags: report, laravel-5.8, dompdf

I have to use the DomPDF package in the laravel(5.8) project. But we face a Maximum execution time Error in the report creation process.

I get a query result in **6sec**.
My query count is **1971.**

My package details:
barryvdh/laravel-dompdf: **"0.8.7"**
laravel/framework": **"5.8"**

**My sample code for report creation:**

> $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.demodetails.viewreport',compact('alldetails'));
>
> return $pdf->download('demoreport.pdf');

But the report creation process takes more time to load.

I really appreciate it if anyone can suggest it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the **"barryvdh/laravel-snappy"** package instead of "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf". I got the result in **16 secs.**(My total records are 1971)

> Note: Dompdf same records I got 1/2 hrs to generate PDF.

Anyone have this problem PL find the below steps to install the **"barryvdh/laravel-snappy"** package.

Step1:
composer require barryvdh/laravel-snappy

a) Add provider
Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider::class,

b)Add Aliases
'PDF' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf::class,
'SnappyImage' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyImage::class,

c)Publish
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider"

Step2:
composer require wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows

a)Set binary path in snappy file.

In **live server**(Linux) follow the below link and setup the wkhtmltopdf and wkhtmltoimage, After set the binary path values.

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/959152/how-can-i-install-the-latest-wkhtmltopdf-on-ubuntu-16-04